# Avoid superfluous parentheses in LaTeX from Maxima's `tex` function

Tags: tex, maxima

I want to use Maxima to simplify expressions and print the result in LaTeX.
However, if I enter

```
tex(-2*y);
```

I get

> $$-\left(2\,y\right)$$

which roughly prints as `-(2y)` after `latex`.
Is there a way to tell Maxima to drop the unnecessary parentheses around `2y` in the LaTeX output?

Comment: Bernhard, unfortunately the display of parentheses has gone back and forth over the years -- there have been cases where necessary parentheses were missing, but then fixing that has introduced unnecessary parentheses elsewhere. I will search the change history to see if I can figure out a work-around, or better yet, how to get the parentheses just right. (Of course in the meantime, anyone else is welcome to answer this question.)